# load config file (project.properties) at runtime via command prompt in java

Tags: java, cmd, properties-file

I would like to load properties file via command prompt in java.

Properties file name: project.properties

```
java -classpath .;test.jar; com.project.Main
```

What 'll be the command if I'll load the properties files via command prompt.

Thank in advance.

I have executed the below mentioned command on command prompt but not get any output.

java -classpath .;test.jar; -DPROP_FILE="C:\Program Files\DemoApp\config\project.properties" com.project.Main

Answer (score 9):

Send file path as below format,

```
java -classpath .;test.jar; -DPROP_FILE=conf\project.properties com.project.Main
```

Use below code for getting property file

```
String propFile = System.getProperty("PROP_FILE");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile));
```

Thanks.

Comment: I executed the below mentioned command but unable to read that file. 

java -classpath .;test.jar; -DPROP_FILE="C:\Program Files\DemoApp\config\project.properties" com.project.Main

Comment: It should be works fine. pls post your java code here.

Answer (score 3):

Run `java -classpath .;test.jar; com.project.Main project.properties`, than read this argument in your main method and load the file.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String fileName = args[0];
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
     prop.load(in);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java -classpath c:\java Client test.properties
```

"c:\java" is classpath - change to your java classpath

Answer (score 1):

In your code load it as a `java.util.ResourceBundle`:

```
ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("project");
```

You can access the properties via the [ResourceBundle API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Put your properties file on the classpath when starting your app:

```
java -classpath .;test.jar;project.properties com.project.Main
```