# Java command line to specify system properties file

Tags: java

Does Java have any command-line way of specifying a classpath-relative file from which it will load system properties (similar to -D properties)?

Comment: Are you looking to specify a file rather that contains several properties rather than listing each property with a `-D`?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to specify a file that contains one or more properties. This is for privacy reasons (to avoid seeing the information in a Linux ps or top command), and for brevity of command line.

Comment: I think you will need to pass the filename in a `-D` and manually load the properties or use a ResourceBundle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835800/load-config-file-project-properties-at-runtime-via-command-prompt-in-java

Comment: ResourceBundle is for internationalization.  It should not be used as a general means of loading properties.  Just use Properties.load instead.

Comment: [Envvars _JAVA_OPTIONS or JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts) satisfy what you say are your reasons, but not your question

Answer (score 2):

From Java9, you can use `@files` option to import a file as command arguments.

See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111).